# Screen resolution issue in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

Q :i'm currently developing apps to run on iPhone with 3.5inch, 4inch, 4.7inch and 5.5inch. when i load into 4.7 inch iPhone the display is fine, but when it is loaded on 4inch and 3.5 inch iPhone the interface overlap each other.I'm using auto layout, and from my understanding auto layout would does auto resizing? Does anyone know how can i solve this?

Now i answer to my own question!
A: Add a UIView at the bottom and every constraints according to the view and it works like a cham! Thanks guys!

Comment: Could you upload a picture with the layout and your constraints?

Comment: Clearly its an issue with auto-layout. Check the constraints that you have added.

Comment: Your constraints must be breaking,  see console.

Comment: as in when i run in iPhone 5, the resolution displaying is base on iPhone 6, so some of the item is out of the phone size.

Comment: None of the view will go outside screens bound if you set the constraint properly, you must share your console or at least the screen shot of the screen, so that one can help you ahed.

Comment: The console doesn't display any relevant comment regarding UI, maybe i just screen shot and update the question

Comment: Is your container view scrollView or View?,

Comment: It is View, i would not want it to be scroll view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Add scroll view constraints (top, bottom, left, right)**

[image]

**2. Add one view in scroll view and set constraints (top, bottom, left, right, equal width with scroll view)**

[image]

**(Add constraints one by one step 1 then textField, step 2 then textField......)**

**3. Add step 1, step 2, step 3, step 4 label constraints**

[image]

**4. Add all Text fields constraints**

[image]

**5. Add Images constraints**

[image]

**6. Add Button constraints**

[image]

**Update:**

Scroll View is best way, But If you don't want to use scroll view then design screen on 3.5 inch screen xib and add same constraints to labels, text fields and image view

set button bottom constraints low priority like

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, but i would not wan it to be scroll view instead i wan to resizable to fit to different screen size. how can i do that?

Comment: i did add a view instead of scroll view

Answer (score 1):

If you have used auto layout constraints in the storyboard view, then I would advise you check out this tutorial about manual constraints https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwkpyzn7EOM. Hope that helps!